# How to revert to previous value of dropdown if change function rejected in Angular 9

Tags: html, angular9

I have a select box inside a table in each row. The code is as below

```
<td> 
    <select id="role" (change)="changeRole($event,userList.userid)" class="form-control" >
          <option value="admin" [selected]="userList.role == 'admin'">Admin</option>
          <option value="user" [selected]="userList.role == 'user'">User</option>        
     </select>
 </td>
```

The changeRole function is processed if the user have the permission to do so otherwise its rejected. But after the rejection dropdown shows the currently selected value , not the previous one. How it is possible to show the original value in dropdown?

Comment: What do you mean by rejected? Are we talking promises? If yes, please share the controller code. Because I don't think angular just handles such cases (dangerous semi-knowledge right here).

Comment: Rejected means , if the user doesnt have permission to change role, the funtion will not processed and shows your are not authorized . At that time i wan to show the previous value in dropdown. not the currently selected option

Comment: ... What does the function return? `false`?  Does it throw an error?

Comment: yes it return false

Comment: 1. So put that in the question, don't just write "rejected" :). 2. And how come you think that angular reverts the value if the change listener returns false? Do you have any reference to that?